# Can't connect to my database on MariaDB using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

Im trying to connect to a database called "CompanyCSV" using JDBC but when i try to connect it says "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/companyCSV", here's the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connectar {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/companyCSV";
        String user = "root";
        String passwd = "root";

        try (Connection con =
        DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);){
            System.out.println("Connexió exitosa a la base de dades!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error d'establiment de connexió: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed a JDBC driver?

Comment: No, im using the JRE library on the proyect of eclipse, i didnt really installed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Install JDBC driver

To connect your Java app to a MariaBD server via [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), you need to obtain a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver).

If using Maven as your dependency manager, you have to add the following dependency to your pom.xml file. This will download the MariaDB driver for your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the driver first. I never used MariaDB but for most databases you need to do something like

```
Class.forName("<class implementing the driver">);
```

You'll surely find some examples on the MariaDB homepage.

Comment: No. Calling `Class.forName` has not been needed for many years. The JDBC architecture was revamped long ago to use the [Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) to automatically load and register all available JDBC drivers.

Comment: @BasilBourque Though true, the SPI doesn't work if the driver isn't on the initial classpath, but for example on a context classpath (e.g. the driver is in the WEB-INF/lib of a WAR).